# Could not fetch user details: ..springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

When I give domain name in accessTokenUri it doesn't work and reports error but when I provide localhost it works. Why?

**Authorization Server Config.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}


@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("QWE123")
            .secret("abc")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
            .scopes("user_info").accessTokenValiditySeconds(0)
            .autoApprove(true);
}


@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}
}

@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/user/**","/swagger-ui.html", "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**");
}
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth
            .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

}

App.properties
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    resource:
      filter-order: 3
```

**ResourceServerConfig.java**

```
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
public class OauthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html", "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**");
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class Oauth2ResourceServerConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}

App.properties

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
      client:
        clientId: QWE123
        clientSecret: abc
        accessTokenUri: https://example.net/auth/oauth/token
        userAuthorizationUri: https://example.net/auth/oauth/authorize
      resource:
        userInfoUri: https://example.net/auth/logged-in/principal
        filter-order: 3
```

**Error:**

> 2018-09-14 12:00:13.083  INFO 25836 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean
>   'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean
>   [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
>   2018-09-14 12:00:13.095  INFO 25836 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean
>   'restartEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean
>   [org.springframework.cloud.context.restart:name=restartEndpoint,type=RestartEndpoint]
>   2018-09-14 12:00:13.106  INFO 25836 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean
>   'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean
>   [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
>   2018-09-14 12:00:13.116  INFO 25836 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean
>   'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as
>   MBean
>   [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=35d08e6c,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
>   2018-09-14 12:00:13.123  INFO 25836 --- [           main]
>   o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean
>   'refreshEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean
>   [org.springframework.cloud.endpoint:name=refreshEndpoint,type=RefreshEndpoint]
>   2018-09-14 12:00:13.424  INFO 25836 --- [           main]
>   o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
>   2018-09-14 12:00:13.482  INFO 25836 --- [           main]
>   o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase
>   2147483647 2018-09-14 12:00:13.483  INFO 25836 --- [           main]
>   d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
>   2018-09-14 12:00:13.509  INFO 25836 --- [           main]
>   d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom
>   documentation plugin(s) 2018-09-14 12:00:13.530  INFO 25836 --- [
>   main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api
>   listing references 2018-09-14 12:00:13.870  INFO 25836 --- [
>   main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on
>   port(s): 8080 (http) 2018-09-14 12:00:13.882  INFO 25836 --- [
>   main] c.h.dfsc.DfscServiceApplication          : Started
>   DfscServiceApplication in 44.8 seconds (JVM running for 45.324)
>   2018-09-14 12:01:52.271  INFO 25836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/api]    : Initializing Spring
>   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2018-09-14 12:01:52.271  INFO
>   25836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
>   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
>   2018-09-14 12:01:52.292  INFO 25836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet
>   'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 21 ms 2018-09-14
>   12:01:52.990  WARN 25836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   **o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Could not fetch user details: class
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException,
>   A redirect is required to get the users approval**

I have find a lot on this but no success, could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for this.
It was occurring due to clustering. There were multiple servers instances which authenticate and authorise for token. When request for token generation occurs it stores token on one instance but when authorisation request came, it hits on another instances. Where it does not found the token and generates exception.
on localhost I was having one server only, thus working fine.

Comment: It is a good practice to keep the tokens in a memory database like Redis. Spring has a feature that enables that. `@EnableRedisHttpSession`.